# How to make something to let the user change the language in a multilingual website that uses php arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, multilingual

I followed the following tutorial to build a multilingual webpage using php arrays: http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/880915-how-develop-multi-lingual-websites-php

the code:

**files tree:**

```
locale/
    english.php
    french.php
set_locale.php
index.php
```

**locale/english.php:**

```
<?php

$locale = array(
    'title' => 'Title in English',
    'h1' => 'The following in in English:',
    'p1' => 'This is a sample text, in English'
);
?>
```

**locale/french.php:**

```
<?php
$locale = array(
    'title' => 'Titre en français',
    'h1' => 'Le texte suivant en en français:',
    'p1' => 'Il s\'agit d\'un échantillon de texte, en français.'
);
?>
```

**set_locale.php:**

```
<?php

// Get the language from the query string, or set a default.
($language = @$_GET['lang']) or $language = 'english';

// Set up a list of possible values, and make sure the
// selected language is valid.
$allowed_locales = array('english', 'french');
if(!in_array($language, $allowed_locales)) {
    $language = 'english'; // Set default if it is invalid.
}

// Inlclude the selected language
include "locale/{$language}.php";

// Make it global, so it is accessible everywhere in the code.
$GLOBALS['L'] = $locale;
?>
```

**index.php:**

```
<?php

// Include the "set_locale" script to fetch the locale
// that should be used.
include_once "set_locale.php"

// Print the HTML, using the selected locale.
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $GLOBALS['L']['title']; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><?php echo $GLOBALS['L']['h1']; ?></h1>
        <p><?php echo $GLOBALS['L']['p1']; ?></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, I want to make something to let the user click on a link and change the language

Something like this:

```
<ul id="language-selection">
   <li><a href="something should go here but I'm not sure what">English</a></li>
   <li><a href="ssomething should go here but I'm not sure what">English</a></li>
</ul>
```

What's the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass language as part of the query string:

```
<ul id="language-selection">
   <li><a href="index.php?lang=english">English</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.php?lang=french">English</a></li>
</ul>
```

In your code, you are using `$_GET['lang']`, so this should catch it. You may want to mofify the code if the need be.

Answer (score 1):

```
index.php?lang=english
```

OR

```
index.php?lang=french
```